# How to change the form_row behaviour in Symfony 2 / Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

By default a `form_row(form.name)` is rendered as something like:

```
<div><label for="form_name" class=" required">Name</label><input type="text" id="form_name" name="form[name]" required="required" maxlength="45" value=""></div>
```

How/where can I change the behaviour of `form_row()` to for example:

```
<div class="someClassName"><label for="form_name" class=" required">Name</label></div><div class="someOtherClassName"><input type="text" id="form_name" name="form[name]" required="required" maxlength="45" value=""></div>
```

Comment: [How to Customize Form Rendering](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#cookbook-form-theming-methods)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can check this URL: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#cookbook-form-theming-methods

There's a paragraph about customizing form_row().

Here's a simple example. By default, form_row() would create a simple html structure like this:

TWIG:

```
{{ form_row(form.email, { 'label' : 'Your email address' }) }}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <label for="register_email" class=" required">Your email address</label>
    <input type="email" id="register_email" name="register[email]" required="required" />
</div>
```

So, according to the docs, you can create a new twig template, and add class="form_row" to  surrounding the field and label. Place it in YourBundle/views/Form/fields.html.twig and put the following code in there:

```
{% block field_row %}
<div class="form_row">
    {{ form_label(form) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
</div>
{% endblock field_row %}
```

In your template file, add the following line:

```
{% form_theme form 'YourBundle:Form:fields.html.twig' %}
```

Now, the form_row template from that file you created will be used, and will return the following HTML code:

```
<div class="form_row">
    <label for="register_email" class=" required">Email</label>        
    <input type="email" id="register_email" name="register[email]" required="required" />
</div>
```

Hope that it helps.